# DismissViewController unable to access presentingViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, modal-dialog

I have a navigationController with 3 viewControllers that I call as a modal.

When I get to the last viewController I want to press a doneButton that will dismiss the modal navigationController and perform some actions on the presentingViewController, given that the presentingViewController can be of 3 different type.

So in the doneAction of my last viewController, **I want to test what is the presentingViewController but I get (null)** when asking for the presentingViewController.

Here is some test code with NSLogs that show my problem:

```
- (IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void){

        NSLog(@"nav     VC count : %u", self.navigationController.viewControllers.count);
        NSLog(@"nav nav VC count : %u", self.navigationController.navigationController.viewControllers.count);
        NSLog(@"presenting     VC: %@", NSStringFromClass(self.presentingViewController.class));
        NSLog(@"nav            VC: %@", NSStringFromClass(self.navigationController.class));
        NSLog(@"nav presenting VC: %@", NSStringFromClass(self.navigationController.presentingViewController.class));
}
```

And the output:

```
2013-09-25 14:44:40.819 Twinkler[10636:a0b] nav     VC count : 3
2013-09-25 14:44:40.819 Twinkler[10636:a0b] nav nav VC count : 0
2013-09-25 14:44:40.819 Twinkler[10636:a0b] presenting     VC: (null)
2013-09-25 14:44:40.820 Twinkler[10636:a0b] nav            VC: UINavigationController
2013-09-25 14:44:40.820 Twinkler[10636:a0b] nav presenting VC: (null)
```

Does anyone know why it not available ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put NSLOG's before [self dismiss....

Comment: Yes that made it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear what your structure is, but if it was the navigation controller that was presented, you should use it to do the dismissal (actually, it will forward the message to its presenting view controller). Try this:

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```